# Remove loading spinner after a set time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I'm using the following javascript to load and remove a spinner for a web page.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".sk-rotating-plane").fadeOut("slow");;
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
  }, 10);
});
```

What I want to do is change it so that if the page load is taking longer than 5 seconds, then remove the spinner (fadeout), but I still want it to appear normally if the loading takes normal time (load function).

Can this be done with an if statement in javascript?

Comment: for 5 seconds you need to set your setTimeout function to `5000` that `10` won't be enough

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that 10 you have there is in milliseconds which is a really short duration for a timeout.

Comment: @TracyFu, `$('body').addClass('loaded');` is just to change the `css` of `body` once page it is loaded.

Comment: @RayonDabre I understand that. What I'm trying to point out is that 10 milliseconds isn't really worth a settimeout. If the intent is to wait for the animation to finish, a `slow` fadeout is 600 milliseconds.

Comment: And if this is jQuery, you can attach a callback to `fadeOut` that will run when the animation has finished.

Comment: @TracyFu, You are right but OP might have any other intention for doing so, which is not related to question!

Comment: @RayonDabre ...which is why I prefaced with "Unrelated to the question"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var executed = false;
var loaded = function () {
    if (!executed) {
        $(".sk-rotating-plane").fadeOut("slow");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
        }, 10);
        executed = true;
    }
};
$(window).on('load', loaded);
setTimeout(loaded, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks Rayon, it worked perfectly!

Tested it with a slowed resource load. For anyone out there testing loading times for spinners, this delay proxy might be helpful: [link](http://deelay.me)

Answer (score 1):

It's also okay to close it twice.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".sk-rotating-plane").fadeOut("slow");
}, 5000);

$(window).on('load', function(){
    $(".sk-rotating-plane").fadeOut("slow");
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    // more stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using setinterval method to look up regularly , clear timer when loaded.

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    clearInterval(stimer);
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    });
```

Now start a timer to look up time to loading

```
var count=1
var stimer=setInterval(function(){
   if(count==5)
    {
     $(".sk-rotating-plane").fadeOut("slow"); // taking more time
    }
  count++;
  }, 1000);
```